# How to compile this COBOL grammar files?

Tags: antlr4

I'm using COBOL grammar files from below URL:

```
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cobol85
```

From the given source, there are 2 grammar files which are `Cobol85.g4` and `Cobol85Preprocessor.g4`.

Both work like a charm if I deal separately like the following:

```
~$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Cobol85
```

and

```
~$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Cobol85Preprocessor
```

However, I realize, only `Cobol85Preprocessor` able to understand **comments** in COBOL. On the other hand, `Cobol85` grammar file don't. My best tought, maybe I need to import both together into a single file.

So, I created another grammar file named `Cobol.g4` which contains below code:

```
grammar Cobol;
import Cobol85Preprocessor, Cobol85;
```

and compiled it with the following command:

```
~$ antlr4 -Dlanguage=Python2 Cobol
```

Good news, I found no problem compiling it. The bad news, it doesn't work perfectly compare to the previous method (deal grammar files separately).

Instead, I received the below error message:

```
line 1:30 extraneous input '.\r\n     ' expecting {<EOF>, ADATA, ADV...
```

Is there any way to solve this or by design, I should deal both separately? Could anyone please help me with this issue?

PS: I'm not sure if this piece of information will be useful. I'm using `Antlr 4.7.1` with Listener.

Comment: The grammar comes with a Java example. Inspect that to find out what to use. I assume you need both grammars (non-combined), one for a preprocessor and one for the final code.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am the author of these COBOL ANTLR4 grammar files.

The parser generated from grammar `Cobol85.g4` has to be provided with COBOL source code, which has been preprocessed with a COBOL preprocessor. `Cobol85Preprocessor.g4` is at the core of this preprocessor and enables parsing of statements such as `COPY REPLACE`, `EXEC SQL` etc.

`Cobol85Preprocessor.g4` is meant to be augmented with quite extensive additional logic, which is not included in the grammar files and enables normalization of line formats, line breaks, comment lines, comment entries, EXEC SQL, EXEC CICS and so on. This missing code is leading to the problems you are noticing.

The [ProLeap COBOL parser](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser) written by me implements all of this in Java based on the files [Cobol.g4](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/io/proleap/cobol/Cobol.g4) and [Cobol85Preprocessor.g4](https://github.com/uwol/proleap-cobol-parser/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/io/proleap/cobol/CobolPreprocessor.g4). However, there is no Python implementation, yet.